# Hardware architecture for snaps

Tags: snap, architecture

I just published my first snap (mathjump) The package is build on an x86 system. Is there any way to upload different revisions under the same package name for other architectures. I'm assuming my x86 snap will not work properly on other architectures but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload packages for any of the architectures supported by the store (amd64, i386, armhf, arm64, even ppc64el and s390x if you want). The only requirement is that you must be able to actually build the snaps for those architectures (unless your snap is all shell script or similarly non-arch-specific). You can do that in a few different ways:

- Build your snaps on a device (or emulated device with) the desired architecture. This really the only way if your snap is closed source and you want complete control of its build process.
- Build your snap on the (freely available) Launchpad snap builders: submit the project containing your `snapcraft.yaml` to Launchpad and select which architectures you want to support, and it'll build (and even upload to the store) your snaps for you. You can read more about that [here](https://kyrofa.com/posts/building-your-snap-on-device-there-s-a-better-way).

Either solution results in a snap you can submit to the store alongside the other revisions you already have uploaded that target other architectures. It'll get its own revision number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the

> snapcraft.yaml

file you can add the line `architectures: [all]`

```
description: |
This is the description.


architectures: [all]

apps: ...
```

Your snap now will be created with the word `all` in the end.

> snapName_version_all.snap

This indicate that the snap itself can be installed on all the architectures. (Not sure about working).